# Reply to dark post facebook (hidden promoted post)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am looking for a way to reply through graph api to a dark post. Currently when we try to reply to a dark post we get the following error. Error finding the requested story

We also get this error when replying to a hidden post. Is there a way to reply to these hidden promoted posts? (dark posts) ?

Comment: What are "dark" and "hidden" posts in Facebook? If you try to reply to something deleted it is normal that Facebook returns an error, you should handle this in your code.

Comment: Darks posts are promoted unpublish post on facebook. Basically it's a marketing tool to tarket post to specific users.  [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#unpub_scheduled_posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#unpub_scheduled_posts)